# selenium error after entering the header file web driver

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

[header files[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkV6Z.jpg)seelnium webdriver
error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select (wrong name: org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/select)

Code tried:-

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app-root > app-patient-index > app-patient-profile > div.s_detail_doc_wrapper > div.s_patient_detail_tab > div > tabset > div > tab.active.tab-pane > form > div > div.s_patient_profile_form > div > div.col-md-9 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.col-md-9 > div > div.col-sm-5.pl0 > select"))); 

select.deselectAll(); 
select.selectByVisibleText("Married");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItEGF.jpg)
enter image description here

Comment: Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app-root > app-patient-index > app-patient-profile > div.s_detail_doc_wrapper > div.s_patient_detail_tab > div > tabset > div > tab.active.tab-pane > form > div > div.s_patient_profile_form > div > div.col-md-9 > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > div.col-md-9 > div > div.col-sm-5.pl0 > select")));
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("Married");]

Comment: Selenium of which version are you using?

Comment: at which line are you getting the error?

Comment: using version 3

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to select the value from the dropdown.

Note: If the dropdown is of type select.

import to be used is.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Select dayDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='birthday_day']")));
dayDropDown.selectByVisibleText("5");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select (wrong name: org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/select)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at Safety.safety_signin.main(safety_signin.java:60)

Comment: @Sayooj , i have copied your code only but i am not getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Use selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1 , hope it will solve the problem for you

Comment: Are you still getting the error even after using selenium 3.8.1 , Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @Sayooj you can add the full code to your question, don't add your full code to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class is found inside elenium-support jar which you are missing.

You can download jar directly for example for version 2.0a7 from :
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.0a7/selenium-support-2.0a7.jar

Or add maven dependencies

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0a7</version>
    </dependency>
```